# Pandas FIFO in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with items, that I either buy (increase stock) or sell (decrease stock) and I want to implement a FIFO table, which shows which "buys" have been "used up" by sales, and how many are remaining. For example, given the below table (assuming it is in chronological order):

```
line    item    amount  type    price    
1       A       10      buy     xx.xx    
2       B       5       buy     xx.xx   
3       A       7       sell    xx.xx   
4       B       2       sell    xx.xx   
5       C       11      buy     xx.xx   
6       A       2       buy     xx.xx   
7       C       6       sell    xx.xx   
8       A       1       buy     xx.xx   
9       C       3       sell    xx.xx   
10      A       5       sell    xx.xx
```

The output I am looking for (in the most efficient way possible):

```
line    item    amount  type    price   sold   remaining
1       A       10      buy     xx.xx   10     0        <-- sales from lines 3 and 10  
2       B       5       buy     xx.xx   2      3        <-- sale from line 4
3       A       7       sell    xx.xx   
4       B       2       sell    xx.xx   
5       C       11      buy     xx.xx   9      2        <-- sale from lines 7 and 9
6       A       3       buy     xx.xx   2      1        <-- remainder of sale from line 10
7       C       6       sell    xx.xx   
8       A       1       buy     xx.xx   0      1        <-- no sale as all were allocated
9       C       3       sell    xx.xx   
10      A       5       sell    xx.xx
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently in pandas ? Looping takes quite a while with bigger tables making the user experience when needed to live load this kinds of tables not great.

My end goal is to know, by item type:

- how much remains in total
- price of the remaining items on average, based on the ( ( 'price' * 'remaining' / sum('remaining') )
- price of the sold on average, based on the ( 'price' * 'sold' / sum('sold') )

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? Are you constantly adding rows, or is all the information available at once?

Comment: When the 'calculation' happens, all the rows will be available at once. I recalculate the whole table once rows are added. Let me know if you have other questions / need more context